# I am trying to add a reset button to my clock in Flash

Tags: flash, timer, reset, clock

**I have the Start and Stop buttons working but I can't figure out how to make a reset button and have the clock hands move back to their original positions, please help. Below is my Code**

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var TimerOne: Timer = new Timer(1000);
myStartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startTimer);
myStopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopTimer);
myResetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetTimer);
TimerOne.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveHand);

//START BUTTON FUNCTION
function startTimer(e: MouseEvent): void
{
TimerOne.start();
trace("Timer started");
}

function moveHand(e: TimerEvent) : void
{
mySecondHand.rotation = mySecondHand.rotation + 6
myMinuteHand.rotation = myMinuteHand.rotation + 0.1;
}


var TimerTwo: Timer = new Timer(12000);
TimerTwo.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveHourHand);

function moveHourHand(e: TimerEvent) : void
{
myHourHand.rotation = myHourHand.rotation + 0.1;
}

//STOP BUTTON FUNCTION
function stopTimer(e: MouseEvent) : void
{
TimerOne.stop();
TimerTwo.stop();
trace("Timer stopped");
}
```

**Here is where I'm trying to figure out the reset timer**

```
//RESET BUTTON FUNCTION
function resetTimer(e: MouseEvent) : void
{
TimerOne.reset(); 
TimerTwo.reset();
trace("Timer reset");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If by saying reset you mean moving all handles (second, minute and hour) to primary position you should do something like that:

```
function resetTimer(e: MouseEvent) : void
{
    mySecondHand.rotation = 0;
    myMinuteHand.rotation = 0;
    myHourHand.rotation = 0;

    //You shouldn't do anything with your timer if you want it to continue counting.
    //TimerOne.reset(); 
    //TimerTwo.reset();
    trace("Timer reset");
}
```

That works assuming your initial handles rotation is 0. If it isn't you should save rotation values to variables and use them when resetting.
That would look something like this:

```
var TimerOne: Timer = new Timer(1000);
.
.
.
var sRotation:Number = mySecondHand.rotation;
var mRotation:Number = myMinuteHand.rotation;
var hRotation:Number = myHourHand.rotation;
.
.
.
function resetTimer(e: MouseEvent) : void
{
    mySecondHand.rotation = sRotation;
    myMinuteHand.rotation = mRotation;
    myHourHand.rotation = hRotation;
}
```

And also I would suggest to use only one timer for all handles (seconds, minutes and hours). I see that you move second and minute handles each second (1000 ms.) and hour handle each 12 seconds (12000 ms.) So I would suggest doing that:

```
var hCount:int = 0;
function moveHand(e: TimerEvent) : void
{
    hCount++;
    if(hCount == 12)
    {
        //The following is the same as this: 
        //myHourHand.rotation = myHourHand.rotation + 0.1;
        myHourHand.rotation += 0.1;
        hCount = 0;
    }

    mySecondHand.rotation += 6;
    myMinuteHand.rotation += 0.1;
}
```